# botium plugin failed for the agentzip option

Tags: ubuntu, npm, automation, chatbot

Tried the below command

botium-connector-dialogflow-cli dialogflowimport dialogflow-intents --agentzip "./spec/convo"

error : 
FAILED: Error: Loading Botium plugin failed

Answer (score 0):

You have to install a dummy Botium connector package for this CLI to use (by the way, using the Botium CLI is usually the better option - same functionality in a more powerful tool).

```
> npm install botium-connector-echo
```

And the command line you are using is not correct, for the --agentzip option you have to give the path the the downloaded Dialogflow agent zip file.